# Why doesn't Emacs FTP work for certain sites in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, emacs

This is really confusing me, because however much I search I don't seem to be able to come across this problem on Google.

I'm trying to edit files on a web server using Emacs Ange-FTP on Ubuntu. I type in /user@ftp.host.com:/, Emacs then prompts for a password, which I give, and then it says:

Listing /user@ftp.host.com:/...
forever.

What I don't get is that a) the same thing works in Emacs on Windows, b) FTPing to other web servers with the same technique (and with the same web host) works fine, and c) FTPing to this server using gFTP in Ubuntu works fine.

I can't see why this isn't working and it's driving me up the wall! Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's a firewall issue?  Try FTP passive mode with this:

```
(setq 'ange-ftp-try-passive-mode t)
```